# ASP MVC5 Validation event

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC. I have a user scenario as below

click button Register -> set button Register disabled -> Validate fields (at client side)

```html
if (validate is success)
{
-> set button submit to disabled (prevent duplicate submission)
}
else
{
-> set button to enable
}
```

The problem is I don't know how to indicate the validate event is success or not.

Do you have a solution for this? Thanks you

Answer (score 0):

I understand the problem you have, however, instead of helping you just "*make it work*" I'd rather suggest an alternative (better) way of doing this.

Instead of calling back & updating the existing page, use the [PRG pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). There are a number of benefits using this approach:

1. **Keeps the business logic on the server**. For example, rather than handing an AJAX callback on the client and then subsequently updating the view, you could determine at the server if the request was successful and redirect the user back to the same page providing information as part of your view model on how the view should be rendered e.g. `viewModel.Success`.
2. **Prevents duplicate postbacks**. If you keep the user on the same page *after* they post the form then it opens up the page for duplicate postbacks if the user refreshes the page (e.g. pressing F5).
3. **Keeps your views lean**. Dynamic DOM manipulation can be a pain and potentially a nightmare to maintain / debug. If everything is driven by the server then your view is simply that, a view - it renders once and once only.

Comment: THank for your reply. But actually, I handled the duplicating submission at the server side. I only have problem with the disabled the button...

Comment: @BacClunky well that's interesting because you appear to want to disable the button on your page to avoid that very same problem...